# Workflow Outbound Messages not available

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

We're making an app in Salesforce that uses Outbound Messages, but we realised that not all orgs have them. Is there a way to make Outbound Messages available to orgs that do not have them ?

Comment: What type of Org you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be having **Salesforce Essential** or **Lightning professional** edition. These editions does not allow you to use Workflow and Outbound Messages. You have to upgrade your Salesforce package.

[image]

Src: https://www.salesforce.com/uk/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/

Comment: Yes that's the problem then. We're using the professional edition.
Thanks!